# Fedora 31 install hangs on "started gnome display manager"

Tags: fedora, system-installation

Fedora 31 installation hangs prior to getting to installer GUI.

So Im using thinkpad t580.
Downloaded F31 release yesterday and dd'ed it onto the flash drive.
ive rebooted and selected USB flash drive in boot menu.
Then selected "start installation" from grub menu.
Installer proceed until this line: "started gnome display manager" where it then hangs. So I cant even get into the installer UI...

plz help?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem before when installing Centos7 using `dd` for writing USB. Downloading .iso file again and using `Fedora Media Writer` on Windows to prepare USB solved it. I think it may because that some bytes changed when downloading the image from network the first time. Have you [verified checksum](https://getfedora.org/en/security/) after downloading?

Comment: I did  - I verified chesum. I was able to get it to install by using troubleshooting - install in basic graphics mode.... but now My desktop is fucked up - I cant adjust brightness or change resolution.

Comment: Ive tried using media writer to create bootable drive - but i's just exact same issue - hangs at ""started gnome display manager""